# SharePoint SP1 Uninstallation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to uninstall SharePoint Server 2010 SP1? I hope it can't be done.
Is there any way beyond the rule?

Comment: I am just curious why you want to uninstall SP1. Do you have any problems with it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to uninstall just SP1, I think you're out of luck. Even if you somehow manage to remove it, the odds that your server will behave in a stable manner are slim to none.. :)
A better solution would be to backup your data, reinstall the server without SP1 and then restoring your Content databases from backup.